# Is jQuery datepicker incompatible with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this datepicker that I want to display on a page. I have tried with JQ 1.6.4 and 1.7.2. I am using v1.2.4 of the playframework with Chromium on Ubuntu.

This is the code I am working with. This is my view where I am trying to show the picker.

```
#{extends 'main.html' /} #{set title:'Download Team Data' /}

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td height="50px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="page-header">
    <a href="@{Application.downloadAttendanceData()}">Download
        your team's data for this cycle.</a>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    </p>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The JavaScripts and CSS files are loaded in `main.html` which is a view that's extended in all views. Besides, I have tried referencing these files in the above view. These are the references:

```
<head>
<title>#{get 'title' /}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"
    charset="${_response_encoding}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
    href="@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
    href="@{'/public/stylesheets/demo.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@{'public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="@{'public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="@{'public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@{'public/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'}">

#{get 'moreStyles' /}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"
    href="@{'/public/images/favicon.png'}">
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js'}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery.ticker.js'}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
#{get 'moreScripts' /}
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/testapp.js'}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js'}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js'}"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
function loaded(){
}
</script>


</head>
```

Clicking on the input box doesnt show the datepicker. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Also, change all your script includes, so they uses play routing, this way play will throw an exception, if you misspell a path to a javascript file. example: <script type="text/javascript" src="@{'public/javascripts/jquery.datePicker.js'}"></script>

Comment: I do get JS errors, but they don't affect the app, and I was getting them before I started working on this datepicker. In the meanwhile I will change the includes. Although I do get an error page even with the current way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery UI with Twitter Bootstrap is not a great idea.  Mostly because CSS classes can easily be overridden and cause issues with displaying various components.  Some things may work, some may not, it's not an all-or-none thing.

That being said, you may want to look at [this Bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) plugin.

If it doesn't suit your needs you'll have to figure out what classes are conflicting between jQuery UI and Bootstrap and fix them.  Chrome's CSS viewer lets you view which classes are contributing to an element's style (or lack thereof).

Comment: Thanks, You just confirmed my suspicions. I co-incidentally started using the same plugin while I was waiting for answers, so thats good. It works for me. Only thing is, I am getting the date value from date.valueOf() as `1281335810600000` How do I convert it to human readable values? The number when converted if thought as an epoch gives a date of 23 May 6030.

Comment: nevermind, I was copying the console log incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you info. I never know about bootstrap datepicker before. I have a same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `test_input` as id but are binding the datepicker to `input_test`

Comment: sorry for that, I verified my code before posting, and made the change in the code, but didnot change it here. that being said, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't seem to have jquery.ui.js included

Comment: I got jquery.ui and still doesnt work. I have updated the code to reflect that.