# Rails with Bootstrap - date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I had my rails app all set up to work nicely with bootstrap and I had my form setup with an input field next to a calendar icon, which when clicked, let me pick a date.

I have these gems in my gem file:

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0',  :github => 'derekprior/momentjs-rails'
gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', branch: 'master', submodules: true
```

Then, i incorporated a bootstrap theme and now everything is messed up and I can't figure out how to go back to what I had working before the bootstrap theme imposed its way of collecting dates.

I currently have a form with:

```
<%= pdf.input :start_date, :as => :date_picker, :label => "When do you want to get started?"  %>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <%= pdf.input :completion_date,  :as => :date_picker, :label => "When do you expect to finish?" %>
                        </div>
```

In my vendor assets, I have javascript files for:

```
/*! version : 4.7.15
 =========================================================
 bootstrap-datetimejs
 https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
 Copyright (c) 2015 Jonathan Peterson
 =========================================================
 */
/*
```

I can't copy the content of that file because it is too long and exceeds the maximum post length for a SO post.

Prior to integrating a bootstrap theme, I had the form elements nicely working with a text box next to a calendar icon button which opened to display a calendar.

Now, I have an ugly calendar, underneath previous/next headings with time (hour minute second) functions below as well as 'now' and 'done' buttons. It's ugly. It's not what I want and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

When I inspect element, I can see the following HOWEVER that div class is not a line I have in my form at all. I can't understand how it got into my app in a way that it is revealed in the code inspector but not part of the app:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;"><div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a><div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">May</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2016</span></div></div><table class="ui-datepicker-calendar"><thead><tr><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td></tr><tr><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="4" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">31</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="ui-timepicker-div"><dl><dt class="ui_tpicker_time_label">Time</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_time">00:00</dd><dt class="ui_tpicker_hour_label">Hour</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_hour"><div class="ui_tpicker_hour_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div></dd><dt class="ui_tpicker_minute_label">Minute</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_minute"><div class="ui_tpicker_minute_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div></dd><dt class="ui_tpicker_second_label" style="display:none;">Second</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_second"><div class="ui_tpicker_second_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:none;"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div></dd><dt class="ui_tpicker_millisec_label" style="display:none;">Millisecond</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_millisec"><div class="ui_tpicker_millisec_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:none;"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div></dd><dt class="ui_tpicker_timezone_label" style="display:none;">Time Zone</dt><dd class="ui_tpicker_timezone" style="display:none;"><select><option value="-1200">-1200</option><option value="-1100">-1100</option><option value="-1000">-1000</option><option value="-0930">-0930</option><option value="-0900">-0900</option><option value="-0800">-0800</option><option value="-0700">-0700</option><option value="-0600">-0600</option><option value="-0500">-0500</option><option value="-0430">-0430</option><option value="-0400">-0400</option><option value="-0330">-0330</option><option value="-0300">-0300</option><option value="-0200">-0200</option><option value="-0100">-0100</option><option value="+0000">+0000</option><option value="+0100">+0100</option><option value="+0200">+0200</option><option value="+0300">+0300</option><option value="+0330">+0330</option><option value="+0400">+0400</option><option value="+0430">+0430</option><option value="+0500">+0500</option><option value="+0530">+0530</option><option value="+0545">+0545</option><option value="+0600">+0600</option><option value="+0630">+0630</option><option value="+0700">+0700</option><option value="+0800">+0800</option><option value="+0845">+0845</option><option value="+0900">+0900</option><option value="+0930">+0930</option><option value="+1000">+1000</option><option value="+1030">+1030</option><option value="+1100">+1100</option><option value="+1130">+1130</option><option value="+1200">+1200</option><option value="+1245">+1245</option><option value="+1300">+1300</option><option value="+1400">+1400</option></select></dd></dl></div><div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" data-handler="today" data-event="click">Now</button></div></div>
```

When I search my app code for "date picker", I found a folder called inputs which has a date_picker_input.rb file, with:

```
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input(wrapper_options)
    set_html_options
    set_value_html_option

    template.content_tag :div, class: 'input-group date datetimepicker' do
      input = super(wrapper_options) # leave StringInput do the real rendering
      input + input_button
    end
  end

  def input_html_classes
    super.push ''   # 'form-control'
  end

  private

  def input_button
    template.content_tag :span, class: 'input-group-btn' do
      template.content_tag :button, class: 'btn btn-default', type: 'button' do
        template.content_tag :span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'
      end
    end
  end

  def set_html_options
    input_html_options[:type] = 'text'
    input_html_options[:data] ||= {}
    input_html_options[:data].merge!(date_options: date_options)
  end

  def set_value_html_option
    return unless value.present?
    input_html_options[:value] ||= I18n.localize(value, format: display_pattern)
  end

  def value
    object.send(attribute_name) if object.respond_to? attribute_name
  end

  def display_pattern
    I18n.t('datepicker.dformat', default: '%d/%m/%Y')
  end

  def picker_pattern
    I18n.t('datepicker.pformat', default: 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  end

  def date_view_header_format
    I18n.t('dayViewHeaderFormat', default: 'MMMM YYYY')
  end

  def date_options_base
    {
        locale: I18n.locale.to_s,
        format: picker_pattern,
        dayViewHeaderFormat: date_view_header_format
    }
  end

  def date_options
    custom_options = input_html_options[:data][:date_options] || {}
    date_options_base.merge!(custom_options)
  end

end
```

I'm not sure if this is imposing the styling or elements. I find this process so frustrating, I didn't keep notes to help uninstall the bootstrap theme. I'm losing so much of the day trying to figure out how to get rid of this and am stuck for where to look.

Can anyone help?

What's even more frustrating is that dates don't save as attributes in the database anymore.

Somehow this line of code is being imposed in my app, but does not appear anywhere in my code:

```
    <div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
     <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
      <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
      <a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" data-handler="next" data-event="click" title="Next"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span></a>
      <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">June</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2016</span></div>
   </div>
   <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <thead>
     <tr><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end">
      <span title="Sunday">Su</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Monday">Mo</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">We</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">Th</span></th><th scope="col"><span title="Friday">Fr</span></th><th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td><td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">2</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
      <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
     <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td><td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
     <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
     <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
     <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td><td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
     <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="ui-timepicker-div">
   <dl>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_time_label">Time</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_time">00:00</dd>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_hour_label">Hour</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_hour">
     <div class="ui_tpicker_hour_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_minute_label">Minute</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_minute">
     <div class="ui_tpicker_minute_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_second_label" style="display:none;">Second</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_second">
     <div class="ui_tpicker_second_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:none;">
      <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div>
     </dd>
     <dt class="ui_tpicker_millisec_label" style="display:none;">Millisecond</dt>

     <dd class="ui_tpicker_millisec">
      <div class="ui_tpicker_millisec_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:none;"><span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span></div>
     </dd>
     <dt class="ui_tpicker_timezone_label" style="display:none;">Time Zone</dt>
     <dd class="ui_tpicker_timezone" style="display:none;">
      <select>
       <option value="-1200">-1200</option>
       <option value="-1100">-1100</option>
       <option value="-1000">-1000</option>
       <option value="-0930">-0930</option>
       <option value="-0900">-0900</option>
       <option value="-0800">-0800</option>
       <option value="-0700">-0700</option>
       <option value="-0600">-0600</option>
       <option value="-0500">-0500</option>
       <option value="-0430">-0430</option>
       <option value="-0400">-0400</option>
       <option value="-0330">-0330</option>
       <option value="-0300">-0300</option>
       <option value="-0200">-0200</option>
       <option value="-0100">-0100</option>
       <option value="+0000">+0000</option>
       <option value="+0100">+0100</option>
       <option value="+0200">+0200</option>
       <option value="+0300">+0300</option>
       <option value="+0330">+0330</option>
       <option value="+0400">+0400</option>
       <option value="+0430">+0430</option>
       <option value="+0500">+0500</option>
       <option value="+0530">+0530</option>
       <option value="+0545">+0545</option>
       <option value="+0600">+0600</option>
       <option value="+0630">+0630</option>
       <option value="+0700">+0700</option>
       <option value="+0800">+0800</option>
       <option value="+0845">+0845</option>
       <option value="+0900">+0900</option>
       <option value="+0930">+0930</option>
       <option value="+1000">+1000</option>
       <option value="+1030">+1030</option>
       <option value="+1100">+1100</option>
       <option value="+1130">+1130</option>
       <option value="+1200">+1200</option>
       <option value="+1245">+1245</option>
       <option value="+1300">+1300</option>
       <option value="+1400">+1400</option>
      </select>
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content">
    <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" data-handler="today" data-event="click">Now</button>
   </div>
  </div>
```

TAKING SAHIL'S SUGGESTION

I tried removing jQuery-ui from the application.js file.

When I do, the ugly calendar is removed but the icon calendar that I should be able to click to reveal the calendar doesnt work. A console error says:

```
jquery.surveyor.self-2c34bb6….js?body=1:43 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ jquery.surveyor.self-2c34bb6….js?body=1:43fire @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3233self.fireWith @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3363jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3583completed @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3618
```

REMOVING JQUERY UI FROM APPLICATION.JS

If I remove //= require jquery-ui  from my application.js file, I get the following error. When I do, the page renders without the fuller calendar (with all the time picker bits) but the icon for the calendar does not work to reveal a date calendar when clicked.

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ jquery.surveyor.self-2c34bb6….js?body=1:43fire @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3233self.fireWith @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3363jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3583completed @ jquery.self-660adc5….js?body=1:3618

Comment: I hope you are using `git`. If yes, did you commit your code before making these changes? If yes then we have an easy way of going back. Plus can you tell how and where did you add **bootstrap theme**.

Comment: It's code inside the gem. The gem installs a vendor assets javascripts file. But it isn't rendered in the way it was before including the theme.

Comment: Are you using git for code management?

Comment: yes i use git for code

Comment: Then we can rollback and get the older version of code back, if you have not done any further development. Plus if you can share the link for the bootstrap theme you have used.

Comment: No. I can't roll back. There is nothing in the theme that directly includes the offensive code. I can't think whats causing this, but I can see in the gem documentation that the gem creates the js file in vendor assets.

Comment: Can you please provide the theme link, I just wanted to see the documentation, and if you can just put a cropped screenshot of the datepicker of how it looks now,. We can improve the styling of the datepicker then. And also add a screenshot of how you wanted it to appear.

Comment: Open _application.css_ and see if any `//= require bootstrap datepicker theme` or `//= require jquery-ui` line is present. If yes just comment it out and restart rails server and it should be removed.

Comment: Similarly comment this `//= require jquery-ui` from `application.js`.

Comment: The nature of a gem is that it is loaded from the gem's source. Remove the reference to the gem and rebundle.

Comment: Remove it from my gem file? How will it know to use it? The gem has created input files for date picker/datetimepicker and time picker. It has also created the vendor bootstrap-datepicker js file.

Comment: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-do-gems-work/

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the suggestion. I tried commenting the gem and bundling. Nothing changes. I still get the calendar icon (which doesn't work to display a calendar when you click on it) next to an ugly calendar which has time pickers and all of the rest of the stuff it shouldn't.

Comment: @Mel if you are still in need of help, try me on [github](https://github.com/defaye). I may have missed your email if you sent me one, any emails sent to the address previously listed are only kept for up to an hour

Comment: Can you please tell, how did you add the theme? I have created a dummy application with bootstrap datetimepicker. I am trying to recreate the same scenario. You can access the repository [here](https://github.com/sahil290791/datetime). You can also take this an working example. I have described all the steps in Readme in the repository.

Comment: Hi Sahil. thanks so much for all the help. Straight up, I can see that your application.js doesnt require jquery-ui. However, I think a key part of the problem relates to the suggestion below in relation to using both jQuery and bootstrap. I'm trying to  explore that source of the problem now. To answer your question, I copied the theme files to my vendor assets and tried to figure out the right order in which to add them to my app/assets js file tree

Comment: The below solution is correct, you should either call `datetimepicker`provided by bootstrap or `datepicker` by jquery-ui. Calling only one will solve the problem. No need to remove anything. Only thing you have to takecare of is css styling.

Comment: Hi Sahil, but what does that mean I should do in my code? Should I remove all references to jQuery in my application.js?

Comment: You need not remove references to jQuery, but call only one function for datetime feature, which I think you want to use datetimepicker, put this script on the page, `$('#replace-with-date-field's-id').datetimepicker({format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' });`.

Comment: Im not exactly sure. I don't call it at all (other than by inclusion in my app/assets/javascripts file

Comment: Let us continue [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113631/discussion-between-sahil-and-mel)

Answer (score 0):

Things happen in the following way.
You added [datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails) gem and run its generators. You now have a DatePickerInput class, so when you put as:date_picker, it will use the following css styles - look [here](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails/blob/36d21cec5da7f5b214925804f60e63c61c747023/lib/generators/templates/inputs/date_picker_input.rb) for sources

```
template.content_tag :div, class: 'input-group date datetimepicker' do
      input = super(wrapper_options) # leave StringInput do the real rendering
      input + input_button
    end
```

Now, look [here](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails/blob/36d21cec5da7f5b214925804f60e63c61c747023/lib/generators/datetimepicker_rails/install_generator.rb) - for the .js code that would be run:

```
vendor 'assets/javascripts/pickers.js' do <<-FILE
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    // put here your custom picker options, be applied for all pickers
   });
```

So this call *datetimepicker()* JavaScript function on the previously generated div with datetimepicker class. Now, while the control probably expect to run JavaScript from [bootstrap](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

it instead calls jQuery method of the same name - see [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
   $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
```

This is all this ui-* css styles come from.

And you should *not* use both bootstrap and jQuery UI datepickers together in the same place - see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030266/is-jquery-datepicker-incompatible-with-twitter-bootstrap)

As you talk to use bootstrap seem and control, get rid of jQuery UI from your code.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Do you mean I shouldn't use jQuery at all in my app? or do you mean I need to find a way to limit its use so that it is not involved with bootstrap date picker function. Yes -  i see what you mean about pickers.js file. If I get rid of jQuery completely, I'm afraid other things that depend on it won't work.

Comment: Do not remove jQuery from your project.

Comment: Hm, no, not jQuery by itself, but jQuery UI, which creates those ui-datepicker-* classes. It's strange, though, as jQuery UI datepicker seems to rely on datepicker call and not datetimepicker

Comment: @Mel, provide source of the output page to identify all JavaScript files that's included in your page. Also, as suggested before, find output html code before any JS touches it - using curl or any other tool to just download request content

Comment: @PavelBulanov - I'll try to learn how to use the curl command this week. I tried removing jQuery ui from application.js and show the errors that produces above. I'll update this after I have learned about curl

Comment: @Mel, as alternative to curl (which is really simple), you can [turn off](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0) JavaScript in your browser, open the page and view (unmodified) source. This can be helpful for other investigations as well

Comment: As for the page, pls provide also the div with the inpout field, which goes prior to (generated by JavaScript) ui-datepicker-inline, i.e. the one that should have "input-group date datetimepicker" classes. It's interesting to find out which css styles will have it's calendar button, to find out why there is a JavaScript that calls .datepicker() function on click, and not .datetimepicker()