# Visual Studio 2015 - datepicker function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datepicker

I'am trying to use the datepicker function in my project but I can't seem to use the right .js and .css files.
it keeps saying "datepicker is not a function"
here are the files I use and the script code I wrote:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $("#datep").datepicker();

});

</script>
```

can someone give me a cdn link for the right files for VS2015 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jquery datepicker** try to initialize before the page is loaded so the issue was there force it to initialize after page load. Just add datepicker initializer code between curly brace below. It Will solve your Issue.

```
  $(function () {


    });
```

Comment: you mean like this? 

$(function () {

    $("#datep").datepicker();

});
...... that's what gives me the error

Comment: I did but it keeps saying the datepicker is not a function, here the exact error message: ""Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function""

Comment: It seems  no error it must have worked once just set  layout null using  @{
    Layout = null;
}   and try it have to work.

Comment: nvm, it worked!, it seems I've used the right code all this time and the only solution was to close VS and open it again!
thanks for your time.

Comment: thanks, I know it feels bad when the solution is so silly we never think of it XD

Answer (score 2):

*If you are using MVC , Jquery.js file is bundled and is added in Layout page since it is added in layout again if you add jquery in view conflict occurs so better add jquery.ui in bundle and bundle in layout or add link of js in layout page. Hope this will help you*

Comment: I already deleted the layout page and made sure to only add the files in the wanted view, but it keeps saying the datepicker function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project are you working on? MVC? Any chance you are using Bootstrap? From what I've gathered, JQuery UI elements (like JQuery Datepicker) don't work very nicely together with Bootstrap. You might want to use Bootstrap datepicker instead.

[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030266/is-jquery-datepicker-incompatible-with-twitter-bootstrap).

Comment: I'll try the bootstrap datepicker and see what happens

Comment: I tried http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/#.... still error : datepicker is not a function

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: nope but thought maybe try it, anyway thanks for the replies it got solved, seems all I had to do from the start was to re-launch VS2015.